# pygtk FileChooserDialog slows down interpreter

Tags: python, pygtk, ipython

I'm trying to use FileChooserDialog to get a native gnome dialog box in a python script.  After the script executes, my `ipython -pylab` prompt experiences a significant slow down.  This problem also exists from a plain python prompt.  I've isolated the problem to the dialog box.  The following example (which has been posted elsewhere as a pygtk example) illustrates the issue:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
class FileChooserDialog:
    def __init__(self):
        filechooserdialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog("FileChooserDialog Example", None, gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL, gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))        
        response = filechooserdialog.run()
        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            print "Selected filepath: %s" % filechooserdialog.get_filename()
        filechooserdialog.destroy()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    FileChooserDialog()
```

After running the script, my hard drive light seems to flash after any key is typed in from the keyboard - very strange behavior!  I do not have the problem with deprecated `gtk.FileSelection` or any other gtk window objects.

I'm currently running, python 2.6.5, gtk 2.21.1, pygtk 2.17.0 in ubuntu 10.04.  In general this dialog seems to be flaky; I've also had some issues with the window not destroying itself when executed certain ways within scripts.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your indentation from lines 6-10 is wrong. Upon creation of the class, that will all be executed, and not when you initiate it.

Comment: Indentation fixed; the code was not copied correctly.  (Python will report an IndentationError with the original).  Problem still exists. I was hoping someone would try to see if they could reproduce the issue on their system.

Answer (score 0):

From running this in the IDLE, here's the steps I can see going on  for me -

1. The script starts and the file chooser loads
2. The interpreter locks as it waits for `FileChooserDialog.run()`
3. The interpreter resumes when I click to remove it

Which is nothing what like you describe, so I can only assume it is some esoteric, weird error.

I'm on a little older system (and a totally different distro), so I run:

- Python 2.6.4
- PyGTK 2.16.0
- GTK 2.18.7

---

Just for correctness (not *necessairly* dealing with the problem, though who knows...) remember to call `.destroy()` for the dialog after you call `.run()` on it.P

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  To be clear the problem (slowdown in the python session) occurs after the above scripts runs (and the dialog is destroyed).  In other words, I see the problem after step 3 of your answer.  In investigating this, I found that I don't have the problem in WinXP 32.

Comment: Also, I've found the problem seems to exist at the initialization of a FileChooserDialog object, prior to .run(), and it doesn't go away after .destroy(). In other words, you can test this issue by simply executing "gtk.FileChooserDialog()" (after importing gtk).  I suspect that a subset of the python community really cares about this issue - where I'm trying to interact with (numpy) objects after a script runs (like one potentially would in Matlab).

Comment: The part about XP is *really weird*, as  GTK doesn't have the best reputation on Windows systems... install VirtualBox and run another distro (like Zenwalk or Mandriva) to see if this issue persists. I  *think* it won't.